# join query for merging three tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to join project table with department table based on department_string_id and join users table with project_owner_id in project table with users table aceid for the condition project.project_owner_id=users.aceid

```
desired query (working fine)
 select p.*,d.department_head_aceid from project as p inner join department as d on p.department_string_id=d.department_string_id inner join users as u on p.project_owner_id=u.aceid where u.id='4'
```

Laravel query

```
 $approver_id_roles=DB::table('project')
         ->join('department', 'project.department_string_id', '=', 'department.department_string_id')->join('users','project.project_owner_id','=','users.aceid')
         ->where('project.project_owner_id','=','users.aceid')
         ->select('department.department_head_aceid')->get();
```

caught below error

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

What I did wrong here

Comment: The error is because you are sending to a post (not get) route and the token is not there or expired.

Comment: show your routes and method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid CSRF attack we want add token in form. 
[Laravel token](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection)

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```